# Nginx how to serve simple http website on a different port

Tags: http, nginx, port

I have nginx, and two simple static sites (one index.html for each).
I would like to achieve that the other site is available at a different port, something like this:

```
http://example.com -> served from /etc/share/nginx/html/site1/index.html

http://example.com:12345 -> served from /etc/share/nginx/html/site2/index.html
```

I tried it like so for the non-80 port:

```
server {
   listen 12345;
   server_name example.com;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html/site2;

   location / {
      index index.html;
   }
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, solved, I had to enable the port on the firewall (I'm on CentOS 8):

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=12345/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```